# WPF Dynamic Resource to change colour for entire application

Tags: wpf

Description of my issue

We have a solidColourBrush with a defined colour. For your reference these three colours are used throughout the application. In theory if we keep these colours in our database, this means that we can re-skin the app by amending the colour in the database rather than in code and have to re-build the app every time we need a colour change.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xLightGreyBrush" Color="{StaticResource xLightGreyColour}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xLightYellowBrush" Color="{StaticResource xLightxYellowColour}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="xYellowBrush" Color="{StaticResource xYellowColour}" />
```

What I want to do is to load these colours from the database. Now I have created the appropriate classes and those values are sent from the database to the front end.  So now instead of using xLightGreyColour and xLightxYellowColour defined in XAML these would be in a list populated by the values in the database:

```
IEnumerable<ColourSchemeObject>
```

The ColourSchemeObject has three properties.

```
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
```

So the Code would map to what brush we want to assign the colour to, and value would be the colour value such as xLightGreyColour but in hex format.

What would be the best way of actually executing this, if it's even possible. Thank you to anyone that can shed some information! :)

Comment: Use Dynamic Resources Instead. Whenever there is changes in DB. Refresh your local  repository and Update Brush Classes

Comment: Thanks! yeah that's what I will have to do. However, I wasn't sure how to wire all this up. I'm back to this task today, so any help is well appreciated.